# SSL-Login Redirect Domain/Content Mismatch with IE8

Tags: spring, internet-explorer-8, spring-security

We have a Spring 4.0 application with Spring Security to handle our login. Everything works fine with all operating systems and browsers (!). But there is an issue with Windows XP and Internet Explorer 8 (Win 7/IE8 works!).

On Login (test.example.com) we are redirected from http to https, which is expected. But upon looking up the delivered content we see content from a different subdomain (live.example.com)! The header of the http-request contain test.example.com, but the response is from live.example.com.

How is that possible? And how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a SNI problem if you use any kind of load balancer, https proxy or more than 1 ssl certificate on the same IP.

IE on Windows XP does not support SNI. Test it @ https://alice.sni.velox.ch

How to fix this:
For load balancer / proxies:
Try to match the https destination from the host header and not with SNI.

For Apache / nginx:
One IP per SSL certificate

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the problem we were facing!